# Mysql with python: problems with utf8 encoding

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, character-encoding, mysql-python

When insert a record in the base get an encoding error.

The connection is made like this:

```
conexion = mysql.connector.connect(host='200.**.**.**',
                                       database='database',
                                       user='user',
                                       password='password',
                                        port=3306,
                                    charset='utf8'
                                  )
```

With this preprocessing:

```
nombre = nombre.replace("\'", "\\'")
```

The query:

```
query = "INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES('"+nombre[0:250]+"')"
cursor = conexion.cursor()
cursor.execute(query)
conexion.commit()
cursor.close()
```

The error message is:

```
DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x95\x8B\xF0\x9D...' for column 'nombre' at row 1
```

In the database the field is defined as:

```
`nombre` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
```

Try the following alternatives with the respective error messages:

a)

```
nombre = nombre.replace("\'", "\\'")
nombre = str(nombre, 'utf-8')
query = "INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES('"+nombre[0:250]+"')"

TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

b)

```
nombre = nombre.replace("\'", "\\'")
nombre = nombre.decode('utf-8')
query = "INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES('"+nombre[0:250]+"')"

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

c)

```
nombre = nombre.replace("\'", "\\'")
nombre.decode('unicode_escape').encode('iso8859-1').decode('utf8')
query = "INSERT INTO table(field) VALUES('"+nombre[0:250]+"')"

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'
```

Any other solution?
Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: How is column `nombre` defined in the database…?

Comment: Also, that's not how you do SQL queries! Use parameterised queries! Something like `cursor.execute('INSERT ... VALUES (%s)', (nombre,))`. Then skip the `replace` as well.

Comment: @deceze edit the post with more information. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved in this way:

```
cursor = conexion.cursor()
cursor.execute('SET NAMES utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8;')
cursor.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8;')
cursor.close()
```